# php checkbox update, insert, delete mysql records

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I've searched quite a bit for this but nothing has seem to to come up which is strange because I think it would be something that's something quite easy to implement. Basically I have a list of items which the user selects, what I want to do is update the values in the database according to the checkboxes selected basically the following scenarios:

The id assigned in the checkbox array is already in the DB and nothing needs to happen, or can be updated with the same value.

The id assigned in the checkbox array needs to be added to the database.

The id ISN't assigned in the checkbox array and therefor must be deleted from the DB.

has anyone got any code they worked with that does this?

### EDIT:

the table is simple with two things being updated:

id_text and id_product

array coming from $_POST is:

```
Array ( [text] => 
         Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 ) // the values that need to be inserted, updated, or deleted if they don't exist here.
         [textValue] => ALL OF THEM
         [id] => 33 // the 'id_product value'
         [update] => update )
```

Comment: what is table structure? what are the values u want to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True, without any code or database squema is pretty hard to help, but if I understand correctly you can just:

1. Delete all values on DB.
2. Loop through the ids passed in POST or GET and insert them on DB.

Comment: @Dan - wait a minute, what if your database connection fail or other exception happen after you deleted all values on DB?

Comment: @ajrreeal could wrap it all up in an transaction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do an replace for every id passed. Replace behaves like insert i the entry does not exist and like update if it exists. I can not give you more details becuase I do not know your table structure
2. Delete all items that have a id that is not in your array. you can select those with "in":

   ...WHERE id_product NOT IN (1,3,5,8) AND......

   you can easily generate this by using

   $idCondition = 'id_product NOT IN (' . implode(',',$yourArrayName) . ')';

About REPLACE:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/replace.html

About IN:

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/tutorial_mysql_in_and_between.php3

**EDIT:** I just realized that some people might have objections on my deinition of REPLACE. What REPLACE actually does is deleting the row if it already exists and then do an INSERT.